# Convert python requests to http flutter

Tags: python, flutter, http, python-requests

I have a python code like:

```py
files = {
    'image_url': (None, ''),
    'image_content': (None, ''),
    'filename': (None, ''),
    'h1': (None, 'en'),
    'bih': (None, '179'),
    'biw': (None, '1600'),
    'encoded_image': (None, open(file,'rb')),
}
response = requests.post('https://www.google.co.in/searchbyimage/upload', files=files, allow_redirects=True)
```

The curl command is
`curl -F encoded_image=@/path/to/image.jpg https://www.google.de/searchbyimage/upload`

How can I convert this code to flutter HTTP or any other package (like dio)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import `dio` package.

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File file) async {
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        // your other data here
        "file":
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:fileName),
    });
    response = await dio.post("https://www.google.co.in/searchbyimage/upload", data: formData);
    return response.data;
}
```